# Assume $a_1 > 1$. Find the limit of $a_{n+1} = 2 - ( \frac{1}{a_n} + a_n )$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Attempt:

$$L = 2 - \frac{1}{L} $$

By solving this, I can get that $L=1$. However, in trying to prove the limit existence, I want to do this by proving the recursive sequence is bounded and monotonic. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this for a recursive sequence. What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. convergency is not true in general. For $a_{1}=2$, $a_{3}$ is infinity. Generally, nontrivial precondition $\forall_{n}a_{n}\neq1$ is necessary
2. Correct equation is $2L=2-\frac{1}{L}
    $, without real roots

Comment: If $a_1=2$, why $a_3$ is infinity?

Comment: Why is the equation $2L=2-\frac1L$?

Comment: 1] Sorry, mistake :/ 
For $a_{1}=1$

2] Equation is $L=2-L-1/L$, i.e. $2L=2-1/L$

Comment: However OP has assumed that $a_1>1$...

Comment: Yes. My blunder ;)

Answer (score 2):

The sequence is diverge. Because $a_{2n}\leq 0$ and $a_{2n+1}\geq 4$ for all $n\geq 1.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**: if $a_n>1$ then $a_{n+1}<0$:
$$
a_{n+1}=-\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_n}}-\sqrt{a_n}\right)^2<0.
$$
And if $a_{n}<0$ then $a_{n+1}>1$:
$$
a_{n+1}-1=1-\left(a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)>1>0.
$$
From these, what can you say about $a_1,a_3,a_5,\ldots$ and $a_2,a_4,a_6,\ldots$?